# Wiring Relay & Horn on Golf Cart

Tags: relay

I've had this wired up in the past but I forget how it was done and some things came apart. We have a simple 12v horn and relay. The relay is a KUMP 7D58-12. Here (https://i.stack.imgur.com/82O88.jpg) are some pictures of how I think it should be wired. I don't want to try anything before I have it checked so that's my question. The 12v is supplied from a 48v>12v converter already installed.

If I missed something in there that needs explained, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

The relay has two independent NO contacts. Doesn't matter which is used. Also, the specific wiring locations of the horn and switch don't matter either, but this is the general idea.

[image]

Comment: That looks like the horn is on the hot side of the relay. Shouldn't it be on the ground side?

Comment: @robk `the specific wiring locations of the horn and switch don't matter either` It could be on either side, but if safety dictates it should be on the low side, then by all means.